# Using c and bit shifting to solve a specific requirement

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-shift

I have a 16 letter alphabet. Given a sentence, I would like to count the frequency of each letter, and then encapsulate all frequencies in one number using clever bit shifting. Lets assume those sentences are always 100 letter each, and assuming no letter occurs more than 31 times, I would like something like this:

```
A: occurs 2 times -> 0010
B: occurs 10 times -> 1010
C: occurs 7 times -> 0111
```

Etc.

Now, I would like to concatenation those like this:
001010100111...

I just concentrated the frequencies above. To store the number easily, I wanted to convert the binary above to a 64 bit unsigned int.

My other requirement is to have that long and re extract the frequencies back per letter. So, I will need to be able to generate the decimal then parse it into the individual frequency bits.

How would I do that in c? I can do bit shifting and additions of those frequencies but that means I'm overlapping frequencies.  The other issue is when extracting frequencies, how do I know how many bits to shift since trailing 0s are insignificant and not saved in the decimal but they are really important in my algorithm.

Any clever ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Up to 31 means it takes 5 bits to store the count of a letter, times 16 letters means 80 bits - you have a problem there. Is it OK to make the limit per letter 15? Or to have only 12 letters?

Comment: Your specifications would only allow for at most, 15 occurrences of a single letter from the alphabet.

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean 15 at most.

Comment: A solution could meet your originally requirements of 16 letters, 31 max usages, 100 long sentence by using Hamming codes to fit in a 64 bit int.  It would not be a concatenation as you suggested, but doable.

Answer (score 5):

You have two problems: a mathematical problem and a coding problem.

Let's ignore the math problem for the moment. You can build an array with 16 integers and count the occurrences of each letter when you scan the text. If you assume that no letter occurs more than 15 times, then you don't have to worry about overflow and you can put the counts into your 64-bit integer easily enough. You'd write:

```
int counts[16];  // has the counts
unsigned long long freqs;  // this holds the encoded value

// after you compute the counts
freqs = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    freqs <<= 4;
    freqs |= (counts[i] & 0xF);
}
```

At that point, the count for the first letter is in the top 4 bits of `freqs`, and the count for the last letter is is the bottom four bits. All the other counts are in between. Each one occupies exactly 4 bits of that 64-bit number.

Now, if you want the ability to do this with much larger text, or a letter can occur more often than 15 times, you have to scale your numbers after counting so that the maximum is no larger than 15. That's the math problem I alluded to. I think you can probably figure out how to handle that one. You just have to scale the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the advantage is that there will be no need of intermediate array to count your letters:

```
int ch_to_index(char ch) { return ch-'A'; }

unsigned long long get_freq(unsigned long long freq, int index)
{
    return (freq>>(4*index))&0x0f;
}


unsigned long long set_freq(unsigned long long freq, int index, unsigned long val)
{
    return (  ((val&0x0fULL)<<(4*index)) | (freq & (0xffffffffffffffffULL ^ (0xfULL<<(4*index)))) );
}

unsigned long long inc_freq(unsigned long long freq, int index)
{
    return set_freq(freq, index, get_freq(freq, index) +1) ;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    unsigned long long freq=0;
    freq = inc_freq(freq, ch_to_index('A'));
    freq = inc_freq(freq, ch_to_index('A'));
    freq = inc_freq(freq, ch_to_index('B'));

    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        printf("%i = %i\n", i, (int)get_freq(freq, i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of this approach! Kudos!

Comment: I just thought that there is a need to get rid of an large array. You can sometimes optimize a code for speed by placing all data into one or more variables that fit into one CPU register. Those will not need an access to cache or RAM. Or when coding for MCU's that have just like 1k or less RAM, bit optimalisations could be helpful.

Comment: Interesting approach and possibly quite fast if you can guarantee that the value will stay in a register. And if you're sure that no count will exceed 15.

Comment: This solution works well, but you will need to change the line: 'return (  ((val&0x0f)<<(4*index)) | (freq & (0xffffffffffffffffULL ^ (0xf<<(4*index)))) );' with 'return (  ((val&0x0fLLU)<<(4*index)) | (freq & (0xffffffffffffffffULL ^ (0xfLLU<<(4*index)))) );' so you can save frequencies for letters over order 8.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should suffice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const static int  SIZE       = 16;
const static char ALPHABET[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

char* getFrequency(char* str);
uint64_t getFrequencyNumber(char* freq);

int main() {
  char*    str     = "1337CODE";
  uint64_t freqNum = getFrequencyNumber(getFrequency(str));
  printf("%llu\n",freqNum);
  return 0;
}

char* getFrequency(char* str) {
  int i,j;
  char* freq = (char*) calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
  for(i=0; str[i]; ++i)
    for(j=0; j<SIZE; ++j)
      if(str[i] == ALPHABET[j])
        if(freq[i] < 15) //ignore overflow
          (freq[j])++;
  return freq;
}

uint64_t getFrequencyNumber(char* freq) {
  uint64_t i,num;
  for(i=num=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
    num |= freq[i] << (4*i); //use bit shifting to concatenate 4 bit values
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers are good; maybe the following is better though.

It is easy to use just one 64-bit number, and increment individual 4-bit parts in it.

For example, the following increases the counter for the 3rd, 5th and 13th letter (counting from 0):

```
uint64_t my_counters = 0;
my_counters += (uint64_t)1 << (4 * 3);
my_counters += (uint64_t)1 << (4 * 5);
my_counters += (uint64_t)1 << (4 * 13);
```

If your letters are consecutive in the ASCII table (for example, `[a-p]`), it is easy to calculate the index of the letter from its numerical value:

```
uint64_t my_counters = 0;
size_t i;
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    int index = str[i] - 'a';
    my_counters += (uint64_t)1 << (4 * index);
}
```

To print:

```
char c;
for (c = 'a'; c <= 'p'; ++c)
{
    int index = c - 'a';
    int counter = (int)((my_counters >> (4 * index)) & 0xf);
    printf("Letter %c, count %d\n", c, counter);
}
```

Note: my code concatenates the bits in the opposite order comparing to what you want; it seems that this way makes it more clear. You can reverse the order if you replace `4 * index` by `60 - 4 * index`.